# modifying secant method algorithm

Tags: algorithm, optimization, fortran, numerical-methods

my code below uses the secant method to find the root of an analytic function.  The analytic function, f must be specified in the function part of my code.  The code below works well and has no compilation errors.  However, for the problem I want to solve I do not know the analytic function f.

Instead I calculate the function numerically, and its stored as an array.  I want now apply my code to find the roots of this  function. So how can I modify my code such that the input is not an analytic function, instead just an array which I have already calculated?

My working code is below, I assume I just need to modify the last part where I call the function f, I just am unsure how to go about doing this.  Thanks!

```
program main
  implicit none 
  real :: a = 1.0, b = -1.0
  integer :: m = 8
  interface
  function f(x)
  real, intent(in) :: x
  end function
  end interface

  call secant(f,a,b,m)
  end program main

  subroutine secant(f,a,b,m)
  implicit none
  real, intent(in out) :: a,b
  integer, intent(in) :: m
  real :: fa, fb, temp
  integer :: n
  interface
  function f(x)
  real, intent(in) :: x
  end function f
  end interface

  fa = f(a)
  fb = f(b)
  if (abs(fa) >  abs(fb)) then
     temp = a
     a = b
     b = temp
     temp = fa
     fa = fb
     fb = temp
  end if
  print *,"    n        x(n)         f(x(n))"
  print *," 0 ", a, fa    
  print *," 1 ", b, fb
  do n = 2,m
     if (abs(fa) >  abs(fb)) then
        temp = a
        a = b
        b = temp
        temp = fa
        fa = fb
        fb = temp
     end if
     temp = (b - a)/(fb - fa)
       b = a
     fb = fa
     a = a - fa*temp
     fa = f(a)
     print *,n,a,fa
  end do   
  end subroutine secant

  real function f(x)
  implicit none 
  real, intent(in) :: x
  f = x**5 + x**3 + 3.0 !analytic form of a function, I don't actually have this though, I just have the function stored as an array
  end function f
```

Comment: This is a good example of modular programming, and you're well on your way. The function `f` needs to own the array and interpolate between points to find `f(x)`. I suggest you code this separately, and test it using a driver function that just calls `f(x)` at first.

Comment: @Ross Thanks although I don't  understand what your last two sentences mean. I wrote this code because I thought this would be the best starting point for using the secant method. I don't know how to code another separate code which is why I am here. What exactly are you suggesting? How can I get started from the current code I have posted? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not that good an example of modular programming.  For one thing the `secant` subroutine and the function `f` are both external to the program, there's not a module in sight in fact.  This effectively prevents the compiler checking that routines are called with the right types and kinds of argument.  Oh, and OP has omitted `implicit none` too, my thoughts on that are repeated *ad nauseam* across SO.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I added in the implicit nones, thanks.

Comment: in the border case where your array has just two entries in it, e.g. f[1]=-2 and f[2]=2, what would you consider to be f's root?

Comment: @WillNess Sorry I do not understand your question.  The roots of f are found and printed as shown in my code. I can change that function f and it will give me new roots.  Based on the function I have given, f[1]=5 not -1.  However I am probably misunderstanding what you mean but  this code works fine with no problems.Thanks.

Comment: you said "I just have the function stored as an array", so, what if you are given f as an array with two entries, f[1]=-2 and f[2]=2, what do you consider to be its root?

Comment: @WillNess The code  above is a code that uses secant method to find roots of an analytic function.  But, I really need to use a secant method to find an optimal step size to solve a differential equation efficiently, and I don't know the solution to this PDE analytically. I only obtain the differential equation solution numerically by inputting an analytic initial condition and iterating forward. The solution to the equation is stored in an array / determined numerically. So ya my function is  stored as an array, and it's the gradient of this function that I'm  trying to find the roots of.

Comment: I guess Will Ness is probably asking what you assume about the function between the points at which you computed the values and held them on the array. I guess you assume that the function is sufficiently smooth, and I guess that you plan to interpolate the data as Ross assumed.

Comment: @norio  thanks for the clarification. So the function is sufficiently smooth yes and I have its values at every discretized spatial point.(I solve the PDE via discretization). So yes I guess I need to interpolate the data, thanks for clearing that up. However I don't know how to do any of this based off the working code I have above. That's what I'm trying to figure out here.

Comment: A bit off-the-thread, but .. If you have a table of `{x_i}` and `{f(x_i)}`, you can identify the index `j` such that the segment `(x_j, x_{j+1})` encloses a solution by looking for `j` such that `f(x_j)` and `f(x_{j+1})` have opposite signs from each other (i.e., one is positive and the other is negative). So, you will start your search for the solution by `a=x_j` and `b=x_{j+1}`, if I use the names of the dummy arguments of your subroutine secant.  Then, between `a` and `b`, you will not have any more data point.

Comment: If you assume that you can interpolate the data, you have an analytical expression of `f(x)` within `(x_j, x_{j+1})`. This expression has parameters whose values are determined numerically.

Comment: @norio thanks a lot for your comments! That's exactly what I have,  a table of {x_i} and {f(x_i)} obtained via finite discretization. And in regards to the second comment since I do not have an analytical expression of f(x) I will not use interpolation. I still don't  understand how to implement in the code but thanks. Is there an easy way to modify my existing code? Or does it seem like I should just try writing a new one from scratch?

Comment: All that said, I think it doesn't matter here whether your function `f(x)` has an analytical solution or not. I guess you are having a problem with the case where `f(x)` can not be evaluated by specifying only `x`, but you need other data to determine the value of `f(x)` at the given `x`. One way to deal with this situation is to write a class that holds the data and has a function to evaluate `f(x)` using the held data as well as `x` given as the argument. Another more quick and dirty way is to write a module that holds the data as module variables and a function that evaluates `f(x)`.

Comment: @Integrals Sorry, I'm slow to write and didn't read your last comment before I posted mine. Also 'analytical solution' in my last comment should be 'analytical expression.'

Comment: @norio  no problem! I'm trying to digest and understand all of what you're explaining, just having some trouble. Do you see in my code above, the function at the bottom must be inputed as an analytic expression. That's the part I want to modify but it seems it's harder to do so without modifying the rest of the code? I'm slightly confused still.

Comment: You can certainly modify your secant subroutine so that it can be used for a function `f(x)` that needs extra data than `x`. The modification on this subroutine can be small, while you need to prepare a module or a class (or some other mechanisms) for `f(x)` to hold the extra data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I wanted to say in my comments are something as below.

You can modify your `secant` subroutine to take an object of an abstract class (`FAZ`) which is guaranteed to have a function `f`. For example, as following.

`solver.f90`

```
!*****************************************************************
MODULE solver
!*****************************************************************
  IMPLICIT NONE
  PRIVATE

  PUBLIC FAZ
  PUBLIC secant

  TYPE, ABSTRACT :: FAZ
   CONTAINS
     PROCEDURE(f),      deferred, pass :: f
  END TYPE FAZ

  ABSTRACT INTERFACE
     FUNCTION f(this, x)
       IMPORT  :: FAZ
       REAL                           :: f
       CLASS(FAZ),         INTENT(IN) :: this
       REAL,               INTENT(IN) :: x
     END FUNCTION f
  END INTERFACE

!=====================================================================
CONTAINS 
!=====================================================================


  subroutine secant(oFAZ,a,b,m)
    CLASS(FAZ)         :: oFAZ
    real, intent(in out) :: a,b
    integer, intent(in) :: m
    real :: fa, fb, temp
    integer :: n

    fa = oFAZ%f(a)
    fb = oFAZ%f(b)
    if (abs(fa) >  abs(fb)) then
       temp = a
       a = b
       b = temp
       temp = fa
       fa = fb
       fb = temp
    end if
    print *,"    n        x(n)         f(x(n))"
    print *," 0 ", a, fa    
    print *," 1 ", b, fb
    do n = 2,m
       if (abs(fa) >  abs(fb)) then
          temp = a
          a = b
          b = temp
          temp = fa
          fa = fb
          fb = temp
       end if
       temp = (b - a)/(fb - fa)
       b = a
       fb = fa
       a = a - fa*temp
       fa = oFAZ%f(a)
       print *,n,a,fa
    end do
  end subroutine secant

END MODULE solver
```

You can then implement the behavior of the function `f` in whatever way you like by extending the abstract class `FAZ` to a concrete class `MyFAZ`. For example, I wrote it as following.

`myfaz.f90`

```
!*******************************************************************
MODULE my_concrete_faz
!*******************************************************************
  USE solver, ONLY : FAZ
  IMPLICIT NONE
  PRIVATE

  PUBLIC MyFAZ
  PUBLIC MyFAZ_constructor

  TYPE, EXTENDS(FAZ) :: MyFAZ
     PRIVATE
     REAL,     DIMENSION(:),   ALLOCATABLE :: xdata, fdata
   CONTAINS
     PROCEDURE :: destructor
     PROCEDURE :: f
  END TYPE MyFAZ

! ================================================================
CONTAINS
! ================================================================

  ! ****************************************************************
  FUNCTION MyFAZ_constructor(xdata_arg, fdata_arg) RESULT(oMyFAZ)
  ! ****************************************************************
    TYPE(MyFAZ)                         :: oMyFAZ
    REAL,     DIMENSION(:), INTENT(IN)  :: xdata_arg, fdata_arg
    INTEGER :: ndata, jj

    ndata = size(xdata_arg)
    if (size(fdata_arg) /= ndata) then
       stop 'MyFAZ_constructor: array size mismatch .. ndata'
    end if
    do jj=1,ndata-1
       if (xdata_arg(jj)>xdata_arg(jj+1)) then
          stop 'MyFAZ_constructor: expecting a sorted xdata. I am lazy.'
       end if
    end do
    allocate(oMyFAZ%xdata(ndata))
    allocate(oMyFAZ%fdata(ndata))
    oMyFAZ%xdata = xdata_arg
    oMyFAZ%fdata = fdata_arg

  END FUNCTION MyFAZ_constructor


  ! ****************************************************************
  SUBROUTINE destructor(this)
  ! ****************************************************************
    CLASS(MyFAZ),           INTENT(INOUT) :: this

    deallocate(this%xdata)
    deallocate(this%fdata)

  END SUBROUTINE destructor


  ! ****************************************************************
  FUNCTION f(this, x)
  ! ****************************************************************
    ! evaluates the function.  
    ! Linear interpolation is used here, but this will not make sense
    ! in actual application. Everything is written in a very inefficient way. 
    REAL                         :: f
    CLASS(MyFAZ),     INTENT(IN) :: this
    REAL,             INTENT(IN) :: x
    !
    INTEGER  :: jj
    REAL     :: rr

    do jj=1, size(this%xdata)-1
       if (this%xdata(jj)<=x .and. x<=this%xdata(jj+1)) then
          exit
       end if
    end do

    rr = (this%fdata(jj+1) - this%fdata(jj))/(this%xdata(jj+1) - this%xdata(jj))
    f  = rr*(x - this%xdata(jj)) + this%fdata(jj)

  END FUNCTION f

END MODULE my_concrete_faz
```

I used the linear interpolation, just for demonstration. Actually, if `f(x) = r x + s`, then you know the solution without using the secant method.
You will have your own appropriate method to evaluate `f(x)` between data points.

You can use the above two modules as following.

`main.f90`

```
PROGRAM demo
  USE solver, ONLY : secant
  USE my_concrete_faz, ONLY : MyFAZ, MyFAZ_constructor
  IMPLICIT NONE

  REAL,  DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: xdata, fdata
  INTEGER                          :: ndata
  INTEGER                          :: niter_max
  REAL                             :: xa, xb
  TYPE(MyFAZ)                      :: oMyFAZ

  niter_max = 10
  xa = -2.0
  xb =  3.0

  ! prepare data
  ndata = 4
  allocate(xdata(ndata))
  allocate(fdata(ndata))

  xdata(1) = -3.0
  xdata(2) = -1.1
  xdata(3) =  1.2
  xdata(4) =  3.8

  fdata(1) = -1.5
  fdata(2) = -0.9
  fdata(3) =  0.1
  fdata(4) =  0.8

  ! prepare the function
  oMyFAZ = MyFAZ_constructor(xdata, fdata) 
  deallocate(xdata)
  deallocate(fdata)

  ! solve
  call secant(oMyFAZ,xa,xb,niter_max)


  write(*,*) '**************'
  write(*,*) 'normal end'
  write(*,*) '**************'

END PROGRAM demo
```

I compiled, built, and got output as following.

```
$ ifort -c solver.f90
$ ifort -c myfaz.f90
$ ifort -c main.f90
$ ifort -o demo *.o 
$ ./demo 
     n        x(n)         f(x(n))
  0    3.000000      0.5846154    
  1   -2.000000      -1.184211    
           2   1.347448      0.1396975    
           3  0.8285716     -6.1490655E-02
           4  0.9871597      7.4606538E-03
           5  0.9700001      0.0000000E+00
           6  0.9700001      0.0000000E+00
           7            NaN            NaN
           8            NaN            NaN
           9            NaN            NaN
          10            NaN            NaN
 **************
 normal end
 **************
$
```

The `NaN`s are there because your `secant` subroutine reached to the solution before the maximum iteration, but had no way to exit in the middle of the loop.

Here is a plot of the data.

[image: xdata and fdata]